# "Reciprocal" of two path test

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. If
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \ f$$

does not exist, then is there is a path ( passing through the point $(0,0)$ ) along which the limit does not exist?

Remark:

In this context, path is a continuous function $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

If $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist, one can find a sequence of points of the plane $(P_n)$ converging to the origin such that $(f(P_n))$ doesn't converge.

The path defined by $\gamma(1/n)=P_n$ for $n \ge 1$, piecewise linear on each interval $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$ and with $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$ is continuous and $f$ doesn't have a limit along that path.